# How to translate static text in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, polylang

I using polylang plugin to make my webiste multilangual and some of the text / button text can't be translate.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                <h1>Gwarancja przyjętych wartości</h1>
                    <h4 class="pl-20 pr-20 pv-20">Wieloletnie doświadczenie jak i relacje dealerskie gwarantują Najemcy konkurencyjne ceny i optymalny proces działania.</h4>
                    <div class="pv-30">
                        <a href="http://conspectusdelux.com/oferta" class="smooth-scroll scroll-spy btn btn-blue">Zobacz ofertę</a>
                    </div>
```

I have this block of code in wordpress and trying to translate it by polylang plugin .. I instal polylang string plugin but cant see it ... My question is how to add this as a string using pll_register_string or how to translate it in other way . I very poor at Php so that why i ask here you guys .. o advice or maybe code example that i can use and work on my own .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got something like this

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                <h1><?php the_field('sekcja_w_stopce_-_tytul', 'option') ?></h1>
                    <h4 class="pl-20 pr-20 pv-20"><?php the_field('sekcja_w_stopce_-_tresc', 'option') ?></h4>
                    <div class="pv-30">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/oferta" class="smooth-scroll scroll-spy btn btn-blue">Zobacz ofertę</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="separator"></div>
                            <div>
                                <?php if( get_field('link_-_twitter', 'option') ) { ?>
                                    <div class="social-circle-border">
                                        <a href="<?php the_field('link_-_twitter', 'option')?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter social"></i></a> 
                                    </div>
                                <?php } if( get_field('link_-_facebook', 'option') ) { ?>
                                    <div class="social-circle-border">
                                        <a href="<?php the_field('link_-_facebook', 'option')?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook social"></i></a> 
                                    </div>
                                <?php } if( get_field('link_-_instagram', 'option') ) { ?>
                                    <div class="social-circle-border">
                                        <a href="<?php the_field('link_-_instagram', 'option')?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram social"></i></a> 
                                    </div>  
                                <?php } if( get_field('link_-_youtube', 'option') ) { ?>
                                    <div class="social-circle-border">
                                        <a href="<?php the_field('link_-_youtube', 'option')?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube social"></i></a> 
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
```

H1, H4 is this i wanna make multilangual